# uLkJSON под Delphi

Tags: delphi, json, vkontakte-api

Занимаюсь изучением ВК АПИ и написание ПО по работе с ним. Весь парсинг json-на с ВК АПИ я возложил на SuperObject. И он прекрасно справлялся со своей задачей, однако подвёл на стресс-тесте. Я ему скормил ему вот такой вот json:

> {"response":{"count":204,"items":[{"id":154770,"body":"","user_id":1,"from_id":1,"date":1492002564,"read_state":1,"out":0,"random_id":965793707,"fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002563,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002561,"body":"кек","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002534,"body":"лол","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002530,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002528,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002512,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002510,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002508,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002506,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002504,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002499,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002497,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002494,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002492,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002490,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002488,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002486,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1491925392,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1490901947,"body":"test message"}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}],"in_read":155942,"out_read":155942}}

В итоге при попытке его распарсить, он просто падает с ошибкой. Конечно, я бы мог сделать отлавливание ошибок и просто в случае ошибки идти дальше, но к сожалению, это мне не подходит. По этому я первым делом стал смотреть в сторону поиска новых библиотек. И я случайно наткнулся на библиотеку uLkJSON. И вот всё прекрасно, полностью соответствует требованиям, но вот незадача.. Мне необходимо вернуть с jsona не просто некие параметры, а передать в функцию целый json объект из массива вида: 
`[{...},{...},{...}]`. Именно с фигурными скобками и всё как нужно. и всё это преобразовать в строку, Чтобы функция его в дальнейшем распарсила. Но как я не бился, я никак не могу это сделать. Я пытался вытащить так:

```
TlkJSON.ParseText(response_loadmessage).Field['response'].field['items'].Child[0].Value;
```

Но в итоге у меня падает с ошибкой. Не могу понять в чём проблема и нигде не могу найти решения. 
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, а в случае чего, предложения мне других библиотек для работы с json-ом.

Comment: У вас `items` - массив из одного объекта, а не массив объектов. Вам его надо получить? Стандартным парсером, которой встроен в Delphi, этот объект достаётся довольно легко: https://pastebin.com/ENmWSuGL

Comment: Это в данном примере такой массив, обычно внутри него 200 объектов и каждный необходимо вытащить. (Через пару часиков вернусь домой и буду разбираться с вашим примеров)

Comment: Всегда указывайте текст ошибки и код который ее воспроизводит

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример реализации с помощью рекурсивного вызова процедуры парсинга. Накидал по быстрому...

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, System.JSON,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo;
const
  cJsonSource : string =
    '{"response":{"count":204,"items":[{"id":154770,"body":"","user_id":1,'+
    '"from_id":1,"date":1492002564,"read_state":1,"out":0,"random_id":965793707,'+
    '"fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002563,"body":"","fwd_messages":'+
    '[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002561,"body":"кек","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,'+
    '"date":1492002534,"body":"лол","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":'+
    '1492002530,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002528,'+
    '"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002512,"body":"",'+
    '"fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002510,"body":"","fwd_messages":'+
    '[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002508,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,'+
    '"date":1492002506,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002504,'+
    '"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002499,"body":"",'+
    '"fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002497,"body":"","fwd_messages"'+
    ':[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002494,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,'+
    '"date":1492002492,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002490,'+
    '"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002488,"body":"",'+
    '"fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1492002486,"body":"","fwd_messages":'+
    '[{"user_id":1,"date":1491925392,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,'+
    '"date":1490901947,"body":"test message"}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}],'+
    '"in_read":155942,"out_read":155942}}';
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure ParseArrayMessage(AJSONArrayMessage : TJSONArray; Var ARecursiveDeep : Integer);
    procedure ParseMessage(AJSONMessage : TJSONObject; Var ARecursiveDeep : Integer);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var LJSON : TJSONObject;
    LJSONArray : TJSONArray;
    LMessageCount : Integer;
    LRecursiveDeep : Integer;
begin
  LJSON:=TJSONObject(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(cJsonSource));
  if Not Assigned(LJSON) then
    Exit;
  if Not LJSON.TryGetValue('response', LJSON) then
    Exit;
  if LJSON.TryGetValue('count', LMessageCount) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Количество сообщений: '+LMessageCount.ToString);
  LRecursiveDeep:=0;
  if LJSON.TryGetValue('items', LJSONArray) then
    if Assigned(LJSONArray) then
      ParseArrayMessage(LJSONArray, LRecursiveDeep);
end;

procedure TForm1.ParseArrayMessage(AJSONArrayMessage : TJSONArray; Var ARecursiveDeep : Integer);
Var I : Integer;
    LJSON : TJSONObject;
begin
  for I := 0 to AJSONArrayMessage.Count-1 do
  begin
    LJSON:=TJSONObject(AJSONArrayMessage.Items[I]);
    if Assigned(LJSON) then
      ParseMessage(LJSON, ARecursiveDeep);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ParseMessage(AJSONMessage : TJSONObject; Var ARecursiveDeep : Integer);
Var I : Integer;
    LName, LValue : String;
    LJSONArray : TJSONArray;
    LIndent : String;
begin
  Inc(ARecursiveDeep); // Увеличиваем счетчик рекурсивного погружения (для красивого отступа)
  for I := 0 to AJSONMessage.Count-1 do
  begin
    LName:=AJSONMessage.Pairs[I].JsonString.Value;
    if Not (AJSONMessage.Pairs[I].JsonValue is TJSONArray) then //Если элемент не JSON массив
    begin
      LValue:=AJSONMessage.Pairs[I].JsonValue.Value;
      LIndent:=LIndent.PadLeft(ARecursiveDeep * 4);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(LIndent + LName + '=' + LValue);
    end
    Else
    begin
      LJSONArray:=TJSONArray(AJSONMessage.Pairs[I].JsonValue);
      if Assigned(LJSONArray) then
        ParseArrayMessage(LJSONArray, ARecursiveDeep); // Рекурсивный вызов
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: И работает? Добавте пару слов, как это поможет автору вопроса.